# sending an XML to a web service using PHP soapclient with certification I get a 404

Tags: php, xml, soap, ssl-certificate, soap-client

I am dealing with a web service that wants me to use a certificate and sample XML to contact them. I decided to use SOAPclient although I don't really have much understanding of it. My script looks like this:

```
$url='https://the.website.com:443/for_their_service';
$cert = "CERTIFICATE.pem";
$xmlDocument = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:com="http://their.website.subdomain.web.service" xmlns:data="http://data.prescreen.website.subdomain.web.service" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <com:getNameID>
         <com:objaInfo>
            <data:firstName>Larry</data:firstName>
         </com:objaInfo>
      </com:getPreScreenOffers>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$client = new SoapClient($url,
        array(
            'local_cert'=>$cert,
            'trace' => 1,
            'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY
        )
);

$xmlvar = new SoapVar(
      "<ns1:xmlDocument>'.$xmlDocument.'</ns1:xmlDocument>", XSD_ANYXML 
);
enter code here
$params->xmlDocument = (object)$xmlvar;
$save_result = $client->SaveProduct($params);
print_r($save_result);
```

When I do this I get:

> Warning:
>   SoapClient::SoapClient(https://the.website.com:443/for_their_service)
>   [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /path/to/script.php on line 56.
>
> Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://the.website.com:443/for_their_service" in /path/to/script.php
>   on line 56
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://the.website.com:443/for_their_service' : failed to load
>   external entity "https://the.website.com:443/for_their_service" in
>   /path/to/script.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /path/to/script.php(56):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('https://the.websi...', Array) #1 {main} thrown
>   in /path/to/script.php on line 56

I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be getting a 404 here. What are first things I should check to troubleshoot?

Comment: What happened if you navigate to `https://the.website.com:443/for_their_service` from your web browser? By default, you don't need to specify the `443` in the URL since the HTTPS protocol already implied that.

Comment: I get a "warning this connection is not private" warning from my browser and then it gives me a 404. I think the 404 is just because I didn't have the right cert though, or would that probably give me an error message?

Comment: Oh the 404 when I'm i a browser is because it will only except POST requests.

Comment: A `404` not-found error has nothing to do with the cert. You sure you have the correct URL? Have you tried `https://the.website.com/for_their_service` without the URL?

Comment: Yes, this is the right one.

Comment: Where did `SaveProduct` come from? Can you share the codes?